# Symfony2 ajax login remember me functionality

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, remember-me

i have a problem with remember me functionality with symfony2 ajax login.
Here is my firewall configuration:

```
firewalls:
    secured_front:
        pattern: ^/admin/*
        anonymous: ~
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000
            domain:   ~ 
            path: /
            remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
        form_login:
            login_path:  /#login
            check_path:  /admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /admin
            remember_me: true
            success_handler: front_authentication_handler
            failure_handler: front_authentication_handler
        logout:
            path:   /admin/logout
```

Here is what i send to the login_checl:

```
    ajaxData['_username'] = $(this.form).find('#username').val();
    ajaxData['_password'] = $(this.form).find('#password').val();
    $(this.form).find('#rememberMe').is(':checked');
    if($(this.form).find('#rememberMe').is(':checked')){
        ajaxData['_remember_me'] = 'on';
    }
```

Here is the configuration. which should allow remembered users to access "/admin" url:

```
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED}
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_AUTHENTICATED}
```

The problem is, that it doesn`t work. After closing the browser, opening it and trying to access a secured url "/admin" it wants an authentication again.
If you need more information, ask for it in the comment section.
Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `access_control` part looks wrong in *app/config/security.yml* :

```
- { path: ^/admin, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED}
# You should remove following line
# - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_AUTHENTICATED}
```

Comment: Ok, but i have another problem. No cookie is created.